# How to create link to folder in navigation pane of Windows 10 explorer programmatically

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-10, explorer

After reading that it is not possible to create an entry in quick access area of the windows 10 explorer programmatically at the moment i wanted to ask if there is a possibility with an API function or via registry to create a link to a folder in the navigation pane like Dropbox does after installation?

[image: navigation pane with dropbox]

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The screenshot already answered the question, whether this is possible. I assume this is implemented as a [Shell Namespace Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144095.aspx). Also relevant: [How can I make my custom namespace extension get categorized correctly in My Computer?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151102-00/?p=91871) Not for the faint at heart. You should be fluent in COM. See also [Integrate a Cloud Storage Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn889934.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Little bit late, but its working fine for me, That's why adding an answer:

Toy can follow the instructions furnished in this Post: [`Creating a Link in the Left Pane of the File Explorer - like OneDrive or DropBox`](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1116313/Creating-a-Link-in-the-Left-Pane-of-the-File-Explo), Copy those registry entries and save it as a file with `.reg` extension and execute that file from your application if you need to change it from application. or else run that reg file from your system for Applying the changes.

For running registry files you can use the following code:

```
Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", "/s yourRegistryFile.reg");
regeditProcess.WaitForExit();
```